Can an Emergent Geometric-Algebraic Approach Enhance Our Understanding of the Quantum Geometric Tensor’s Phase Independence?
Hello Quantum Forum!
I’ve been exploring the quantum geometric tensor, particularly its decomposition into the Fisher information metric and Berry curvature, as discussed in this arXiv paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.13515
The tensor’s phase independence in defining distance within state space is conceptually intriguing, especially when considering how geometric or algebraic methods could deepen this interpretation.
Question 1: Could an emerging approach that combines elements of geometric algebra and symbolic resonance offer a fresh perspective on phase-invariance within the quantum geometric tensor? Specifically, I’m curious if this kind of approach could provide a more intuitive, spatial visualization of the phase-independent relationships inherent to quantum distance metrics.
Question 2: Could principles inspired by both geometric algebra and morphic resonance create a framework for enhancing coherence in entangled states? I wonder if ideas of resonance and field coherence might contribute new layers of understanding, especially if they can mathematically address stability across phase-consistent interactions in entangled systems.
I’d be very interested in any insights, resources, or thoughts from the community:
• Any research or theories
 combining geometric methods 
 with quantum distance metrics.

• Potential overlaps between 
 symbolic resonance concepts and 
 phase-independence in quantum 
 metrics.

Thanks to everyone for sharing any ideas or related work! Looking forward to learning from this incredible community.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
